# django-admin-tools how to change the "logo" on login

Tags: django, django-admin-tools

I managed to change the menus and dashboard, but how to change the "logo" (Word Django) on login and admin page?

See image:

[django-admin-tools Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqHEa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate this file saving the same structure — https://github.com/django-admin-tools/django-admin-tools/blob/master/admin_tools/theming/templates/admin/base.html

Then after `{% render_theming_css %}` add:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #header #branding h1 {
        background-image: url("../path/to/your/image.png");
    }
</style>
```

Here's the docs on how to overload templates — https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template